# vmware image windows 7 cannot initialize winring0 dll?

Tags: windows, vmware

I've a vmware image with windows 7 and a program needs winring0 dll but when I start the program I get the error message: I cannot initialize winring0 dll but my program works in native Windows 7? Is this a known problem with a vmware image? How can I initialize winring0 in vmware image? In my folder there is winring0 dll for 32 bit and 64 bit.

Comment: Are you sure you are looking for windring0.dll or winring0.dll?

Comment: Ahh I see you are indeed searching for winring0.dll. From what I can see, that driver allows a program to directly access certain CPU registers. It may be that these specific accesses are not supported in vmware. Are you sure that the .dll file exists and is precisely where it is supposed to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you are attempting to find information about your hardware on virtual hardware. This concept alone is likely to be full of problems.

VMware utilizes Binary Translation([See here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_translation)) to execute privileged instructions in the kernel if your processor does not support VT-x (assuming intel) . It is quite possible that it was unable to properly translate the file when attempting to load, due to the fact that the dll very well may contain instructions that vmware was not built to translate, or non-virtualizable instructions, at which point it would fail to initialize. If your processor does support hypervisor assist technology (VT-x or Pacifica), further research may be required. [See Here](http://download3.vmware.com/vmworld/2005/pac346.pdf) for a high level of overview of how VMware works.

Finally, as a last ditch attempt, the dll may require that it load into a specific memory address which conflicts with VMware memory spaces, at which point it would fail to initialize as well. Like said, being inside of vmware increases the complexity of this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the following two links :-

http://www.techpowerup.com/realtemp/docs.php

http://openlibsys.org/

RealTemp is a CPU temperature monitoring application that uses the winring0.dll library distributed by openlibsys.org. It doesn't look like the library will run without actual Intel or AMD processors to act on.

Again, VMWare might be passing through these registers but I doubt it. What software are you trying to run?

Comment: owagh: I've read your pointers but it's not answering my question. Openlibsys is closed a long time ago and winring0 is disconntiuned. I've wrote my own small fan control programm with winring0 but it doesn't work in vmware. In fact I want to use vmware to debug a kernel driver from me and when I test my fan control it doesn't work. Why is winring0 not working in vmware? Can it be a compilation error?

Comment: I'm actually trying to find some more information about this. I still think it's probably because vmware does not expose specific sensors but that would probably cause winring0.dll to give null outputs and not be uninitialised. Will post more if I find something.